# Python not capturing try/except error

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm new to Python. Please forgive me if my question sounds stupid.

The codes below will raise an error but the error is not captured by try/except. I've gone through them many times but couldn't see what is the problem.

Would appreciate it very much if any Gurus here can show the problem to me.

Thanks for your time.

```
import decimal

try:
    Amount = str(decimal.Decimal('2.675a').quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))
    print Amount
except ValueError:
    print 'Error'
```

The error I've got is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
  "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 3866, in _raise_error
  raise error(explanation)
InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '2.675a'
```

Comment: Include the actual error please.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, `2.675a` doesn't seem like a valid decimal string. What's the `a` for?

Comment: @tzaman the 'a' is placed there so that an error is raised. without the 'a', there'll be no error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error being raised by your code fragment is a `decimal.InvalidOperation` exception.  This exception is not a subclass of `ValueError` so does not match your `except` clause.

I would suggest reading the tutorial section on [errors and exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more an overview of how to handle errors in Python code.

Comment: The codes work after the ValueError is removed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't just change it to a bare except: outside of a few well defined cases, you should only be catching errors that you expect to occur.  So if you expect the `InvalidOperation` error (e.g. because you are creating a decimal object from a provided string), catch that exception directly.  If you catch everything, it will hide real problems and make your program harder to debug.